# Write VB.Net code to cycle through all Microsoft Access forms, etc. to export them as text

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to create a Windows Forms application that allows for outputting all forms, reports, etc. in a Microsoft Access 2019 database as text files. I found VBA code (see below) that can do this, from within the access database (via a form), but I want to do this via a Windows Forms front-end instead.

--- VBA CODE BEGINS ---

```
    On Error GoTo Err_DocDatabase
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim cnt As Container
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iTemp As Integer

    Set dbs = CurrentDb() ' use CurrentDb() to refresh Collections

    Set cnt = dbs.Containers("Forms")
    For Each doc In cnt.Documents
      Application.SaveAsText acForm, doc.Name, "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" & RemoveSpecialCharsFromString(doc.Name) & ".txt"
    Next doc

    Set cnt = dbs.Containers("Reports")
    For Each doc In cnt.Documents
      Application.SaveAsText acReport, doc.Name, "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" & RemoveSpecialCharsFromString(doc.Name) & ".txt"
    Next doc

    Set cnt = dbs.Containers("Scripts")
    For Each doc In cnt.Documents
      Application.SaveAsText acMacro, doc.Name, "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" & doc.Name & ".txt"
    Next doc

    Set cnt = dbs.Containers("Modules")
    For Each doc In cnt.Documents
      Application.SaveAsText acModule, doc.Name, "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" & doc.Name & ".txt"
    Next doc

    For i = 0 To dbs.QueryDefs.Count - 1
      Application.SaveAsText acQuery, dbs.QueryDefs(i).Name, "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" & dbs.QueryDefs(i).Name & ".txt"
    Next i

    Set doc = Nothing
    Set cnt = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

  Exit_DocDatabase:
    Exit Sub

  Err_DocDatabase:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_DocDatabase
```

--- VBA CODE ENDS ---

The code that I tried initially was as follows:

--- VB.NET CODE BEGINS ---

```
    Dim oAccess As Access.Application
    Dim sbModuleList As New StringBuilder

    oAccess = New Access.ApplicationClass()
    oAccess.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\" + sDBName)

    For Each oReport As AccessObject In oAccess.CurrentProject.AllReports
      sbModuleList.AppendLine(oReport.Name + " - " +oReport.DateCreated)
    Next
```

--- VB.NET CODE ENDS ---

The Access.Application.CurrentProject object has properties that I want to go after (e.g. AllTables, AllForms, AllReports, etc.). However, though Access.Application.CurrentProject IsNot Nothing, I get an error when trying to access the AllTables property. I will have to look up the actual error message, as I am not at the same computer right now, but I think that it was something like "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'You made an illegal function call.'".

That being said, I just tried the same code on a different computer and it works fine! So, I guess that the question would now become why does the code work on one computer but not on another?

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. And "how to" is a bit too vague. We will help you fix bugs or answer specific questions about your code, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks.

Comment: As the post was worded, the question would be "How can I accomplish what the VBA code accomplishes in a Windows Forms application?" I would be using VB.Net code, which I did not mention, but wasn't critical as I could convert other languages. The code that I tried initially was as follows:

Comment: ...If you're about to post your code into the comments section, please don't. Your question has an "edit" button at the bottom, so you can update your question with the new code and format it in a readable way.

Comment: P.S. Read my first comment again about the suitability of "how to" questions, and also read Please read [Are “Point me in the right direction” questions acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable). You likely need to make your post more specific in terms of a detailed problem. Maybe your pending update will reveal that, hopefully.